# How can I debug why SFTP is not working while SSH is working?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-2, ssh, linux

I have an arcade run on raspberry pi 3 flashed with RetroPie 4.4.

I already enabled SSH capability via `raspi-config` menu

[image]

---

## Test

I can SSH into my Pi perfectly fine, but I can not SFTP into it.

Credentials: `pi`/`raspberry`

**SSH**

[image]

**SFTP**

configure & error

[image]

---

## Questions

**How would one go about and debug this further ?**

---

I'm open to any suggestions at this moment.

Any hints/suggestions / helps on this be will be much appreciated!

---

**cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.84 2011/05/23 03:30:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
  Subsystem     sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
Match User debian,pi,ubnt,ubuntu,vyos,vyatta,bananapi,osmc,xbian,admin Address *,!192.168.0.0/16,!10.0.0.0/8,!172.16.0.0/12,!127.0.0.1
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: "If SSH is enabled, and the password for the ‘pi’ user is still ‘raspberry’, you’ll see a warning message whenever you boot the Pi, whether to the desktop or the command line." https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/ Works OK with FileZilla and proper password!

Comment: @Milliways : I entered the correct password already. I don't know why it won't let me in.

Comment: Because sftp has to be enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: @Janka  can u answer it with the flag of sshd ?

Comment: In your question you state password **raspberry**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a line

`Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`

to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to enable sftp.

Comment: Mine seems to already have this line `Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server`

Comment: Does the file /usr/libexec/sftp-server  exist?

Comment: This line that you suggested is dangerous. As soon as I did it, I locked myself out. I can no longer SSH into my Pi anymore. I had to plug the keyboard into the Pi and uncomment that line back out.

Comment: Any messing with the sshd config may lock you out. Check the log what happened.

Comment: I ran this command `which /usr/libexec/sftp-server` I don't see anyting result. I guess I don't have this installed in my Pi. Is it expected to be install by default ? I also ran basic install and update via the pi set up menu.

Comment: I am no longer log out. I am back in now.

Comment: I updated my posted with my current settings of my sshd.

Comment: Do you have other suggestion ?

Comment: It *should* be installed if it's in your config, otherwise it will not work. Maybe you are missing the *openssh-sftp-server* package.

Comment: How is that possible ? Can I installed it via the pi menu or manually ?

Comment: I tried install. I got this : https://i.imgur.com/EhFO0FL.png

Comment: *How is that possible* – *… RetroPie 4.4 …* ← Because that distribution does not come with it? And yes, sure, you can install it e.g. via apt-get or aptitude.

Comment: *openssh-server* != *openssh-sftp-server*

Comment: Whoop it was a typo on my part. I corrected the typo and get same thing : https://i.imgur.com/JBl3bOL.png

Comment: @kyo can you bypass the arcade client and use the `sftp` command to connect to the server directly? What result does this give.

Comment: I tried it again. It seems to work now. https://i.imgur.com/CaDSPMP.png